# IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [surname], expecting one of [name]

Tags: jpa, illegalargumentexception

My studentRepository class:

```
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public EntityManager em() {
        if (emf == null) {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("teachermanagementPU");
        }
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

    public List<StudentEntity> getAll(String name, String surname, Integer age, BigDecimal scholarship) {
        String jpql = "select u from StudentEntity u where 1=1";

        if (name != null && !name.trim().isEmpty()) {
            jpql += "and u.name=:name";
        }

        if (surname != null && !surname.trim().isEmpty()) {
            jpql += "and u.surname=:surname";
        }

        if (age != null) {
            jpql += "and u.age=:age";
        }
        if (scholarship != null) {
            jpql += "and u.scholarship=:scholarship";
        }

        EntityManager em = em();//JPQL
        Query query = em.createQuery(jpql, StudentEntity.class);

        if (name != null && name.trim().isEmpty()) {
            query.setParameter("name", name);
        }

        if (surname != null && surname.trim().isEmpty()) {
            query.setParameter("surname", surname);
        }

        if (age != null) {
            query.setParameter("age", age);
        }

        if (scholarship != null) {
            query.setParameter("scholarship", scholarship);
        }
        List<StudentEntity> students = query.getResultList();
        em.close();
        return students;
    }
```

I get an error IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [surname], expecting one of [name]
Students.jsp class:

```
StudentRepository studentRepository = new StudentRepository();
List<StudentEntity> students = studentRepository.getAll(
        request.getParameter("name"),
        request.getParameter("surname"),
        request.getParameter("age") != null && !request.getParameter("age").isEmpty() ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age")) : null,
        request.getParameter("scholarship") != null && !request.getParameter("scholarship").isEmpty() ? new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("scholarship")) : null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a blank space when concatenating the strings:

```
if (name != null && !name.trim().isEmpty()) {
    jpql += " and u.name=:name ";
}
```

Same for the other places.

You also forgot an exclamation mark `!`:

```
if (surname != null && !surname.trim().isEmpty()) {
                
    query.setParameter("surname", surname);

}
```

and you can use `isBlank`:

```
if (surname != null && !surname.isBlank()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: if (name != null && !name.trim().isEmpty()) {
            jpql += " and u.name=:name ";
        }

        if (surname != null && !surname.trim().isEmpty()) {
            jpql += " and u.surname=:surname ";
        }

        if (age != null) {
            jpql += " and u.age=:age ";
        }
        if (scholarship != null) {
            jpql += " and u.scholarship=:scholarship ";
        }

Comment: I added blank spaces, but it again gives the same error

Comment: I didn't forget the exclamation mark. isBlank() is not working in IntelliJ IDEA